# Paste to virtual terminal

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu

In a Ubuntu host system I have installed qemu and created a virtual machine with CentOS. The CentOS installation does not have an X server, just a virtual terminal. I would like to be able to copy strings from the host system to the virtual terminal of the virtual machine.

What I found so far is the suggestion to install `spice-vdagent`. If I understand correctly however, `spice-vdagent` requires an X server, which I don't have installed.

So, how can I paste strings to the virtual terminal (if possible at all)?

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable clipboard in your virtual machine manager software (VirtualBox or VmWare).

In Vbox you have to install Guest Additions iso. In VmWare you have to enable it in the virtual machine's options.

Comment: I'm using qemu, not VirtualBox nor VmWare.

Comment: It's that lack of familiarity with KVM/qemu that gets them every time...

Answer (score -1):

Run your Vm and run next command:

```
# yum install spice-vdagent
# chkconfig --add spice-vdagentd
# service spice-vdagentd start
```

Comment: On the second command I get this: `error reading information on service spice-vdagentd: No such file or directory`

Comment: try to run `chkconfig --add spice-vdagent`

Comment: `chkconfig --add` won't work for CentOS 8. Any update?